# Conditioning on type parameters passed to a class

Tags: scala

Suppose I have `MyCoolClass` which accepts a type parameter `T`.
Depending on `T` we want to define `aFun` in this way:

> If ( `T` is the same type as `B` )    `aFun` should be set to `() => new B`
>
> else If ( `T` is the same type as `C` )    `aFun` should be set to `() => new C`
>
> otherwise show an error.

```
class MyCoolClass[T]{ 
   def aFun = ...  // fill this part 
}

class A { 
 // something here 
}

class B extends A { 
 // something more here
}

class C extends A { 
 // yet more things here 
}
```

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that this way. What you can do is instead restrict `T`s in MyCoolClass to require a instance of a type class that would know how to instantiate `T`:

```
trait Cons[T] { def cons:T }
class MyCoolClass[T](implicit ev:Cons[T]) {
 def aFun = ev.cons
}
```

Now what we need is define `A` and `B` and `Cons[A]` and `Cons[B]` (**)

```
class A
class B
object A { implicit def consA:Cons[A] = new Cons[A] { def cons = new A } }
object B { implicit def consA:Cons[B] = new Cons[B] { def cons = new B } }
```

Now in the REPL:

```
scala> new MyCoolClass[A].aFun
res0: A = A@1521d074

scala> new MyCoolClass[B].aFun
res1: B = B@19cdb1cb
```

(**) If you happen to try that in the REPL remember to copy and paste it in a :paste command, otherwise object A and B won't really be companion objects and this own't work